# How can I make the first character of a string lowercase in PHP?

Tags: php

I cannot use [strtolower](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) as it affects all characters. Should I use some sort of regular expression?

I'm getting a string which is a product code. I want to use this product code as a search key in a different place with the first letter made lowercase.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do:

```
$str = "STACK overflow";
$str[0] = strtolower($str[0]); // prints sTACK overflow
```

And if you are using 5.3 or later, you can do:

```
$str = lcfirst($str);
```

Answer (score 18):

Try

- [`lcfirst`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php) — Make a string's first character lowercase

and for PHP < 5.3 add this into the global scope:

```
if (!function_exists('lcfirst')) {

    function lcfirst($str)
    {
        $str = is_string($str) ? $str : '';
        if(mb_strlen($str) > 0) {
            $str[0] = mb_strtolower($str[0]);
        }
        return $str;
    }
}
```

The advantage of the above over just `strolower`ing where needed is that your PHP code will simply switch to the native function once you upgrade to PHP 5.3.

*The function checks whether there actually is a first character in the string and that it is an alphabetic character in the current locale. It is also multibyte aware.*

Comment: +1 but the custom lcfirst function should possibly check that the string isn't 0 length. It avoids the Notice that occurs when it is.

Comment: you should use mb_strlen instead of strlen as strlen counts unicode characters incorrectly. (i.e. strlen("abcä") == 5, mb_strlen("abcä") == 4)

Answer (score 1):

Use [lcfirst()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php):

```
<?php
    $foo = 'HelloWorld';
    $foo = lcfirst($foo);             // helloWorld

    $bar = 'HELLO WORLD!';
    $bar = lcfirst($bar);             // hELLO WORLD!
    $bar = lcfirst(strtoupper($bar)); // hELLO WORLD!
?>
```

Comment: What is the point of the use of strtoupper()?

Answer (score 1):

For a multibyte first letter of a string, none of the previous examples will work.

In that case, you should use:

```
function mb_lcfirst($string)
{
    return mb_strtolower(mb_substr($string, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($string, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ucfirst()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) function converts the first character of a string to uppercase.

Related functions:

- [lcfirst()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.lcfirst.php) - converts the first character of a string to lowercase
- [ucwords()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) - converts the first character of each word in a string to uppercase
- [strtoupper()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) - converts a string to uppercase
- [strtolower()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) - converts a string to lowercase

PHP version: 4 and later

Comment: Re *"The ucfirst() function converts the first character of a string to uppercase."*: Yes, but that wasn't the question. This is an answer to some other question.