# How to replace particular Substring within a String using PHP preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I am trying to replace word or sequence of words in a string using `preg_replace`?
For example:

Change These:

```
ABCExample to abcExample
AnotherExample to anotherExample
XyzAbcExample to xyzAbcExample
```

Leave as it is:

```
xyzExample to xyzExample 
new to new
```

Comment: *I am trying* Where? I don't see any attempt(s)

Comment: why not use explode?

Comment: What is the question here? The function is well documented and comes with clear examples. You _did_ read the documentation when things didn't work as expected, didn't you? http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make the first char of a string lowercase in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801825/how-to-make-the-first-char-of-a-string-lowercase-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `preg_replace_callback` function.

```
$str = <<<EOT
ABCExample
AnotherExample
XyzAbcExample
xyzExample
new
EOT;
echo preg_replace_callback('~(?m)^[A-Za-z]*?(?=(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+$)~', function ($m)
        { 
            return strtolower($m[0]);
        }, $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for [`str_ireplace`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-ireplace.php).

> This function returns a string or an array with all occurrences of
>   search in subject (ignoring case) replaced with the given replace
>   value. If you don't need fancy replacing rules, you should generally
>   use this function instead of preg_replace() with the i modifier.

Sample code (and a [sample program](http://goo.gl/iZv84m)):

```
$res1 = str_ireplace("abc", "xyz", "ABCExample to abcExample");
echo $res1;
```

Output: `xyzExample to xyzExample`